# add Value is not contains in CFDictionary c++?

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c++

I am using the CFDictionary for maintain list.I added some key with value after added values, checking whether added keys contains in dictionary , it returns true.But if i try to get values it is return null.How to check where i missed out?

```
 //Create Dictionary
    CFMutableDictionaryRef fileInfo = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL,0,NULL,NULL);

    //add Value 
    CFDictionaryAddValue(fileInfo, CFSTR("filename"),getstring((uint8_t*)buffer,&offset));

    int size = CFDictionaryGetCount(fileInfo);
    //Return 1;

    if(CFDictionaryContainsKey(fileInfo,CFSTR("filename"))) // return true
    {
       const void* filename =  CFDictionaryGetValue(fileInfo, CFSTR("filename"));
        if(filename ) // return null
        {
        }

    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: Why are you using `CFMutableDictionaryRef` and not simply `NSMutableDictionary`? Just wondering…

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to [pass some callbacks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableDictionaryRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001497-CH201-F11032) in when you create the dictionary otherwise the behaviour of the dictionary might not be what you expect.

Also, make sure that `getstring()` does not return NULL.